# SDWebImage array url not appearing in uiimageview

Tags: swift, for-loop, uiimageview, swift3, sdwebimage

I'm using `SDWebImage` for my `Swift`. I can't figure out why (frankly, HOW) it's not working. there is no image in `imageview`.
so this is what i'm trying. parse query PFFile(s) (url converted) stored in a `var urlArray:[URL] = []`
i have a `UIScrollView` with `UIImageView` inside.

in short: query parse - download PFFile URLs to an array (append).

```
        for index in 0..<self.urlArray.count {
            var frame = CGRect.zero
            frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
            frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size
            self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

            let subView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
            subView.sd_setImage(with: self.urlArray[index], placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile"))
            //subView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            self.scrollView.addSubview(subView)
        }
```

first url image appears ok. then no pagination & no error (array numbers OK) just nothing apears but first pic. used this : `imageview.sd_setImage(with: self.urlArray[index])` is this wrong approach?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the code where you update the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView`. Unless you do that, the scroll view won't scroll for you. The additional image views may be there, but hidden outside of the scroll view's current bounds.

Comment: You were right. I got contentSize in different part of the code.  I've added contentSize correct(right after checking the contents of my Array) and now it shows all the pictures :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`sdWebImage` is a library using for image caching.
If you wanna detect error for downloading image by `sdWebImage` then you apply below code and track response from server.

```
cell.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL (string: sendImgUri!), placeholderImage: UIImage (named: "pro.png"), options: .CacheMemoryOnly, progress: { (i, m) in

                    }, completed: { (image, error, chachType, url) in

                        if(error != nil)
                        {
                           print(error)
                        }
                        else if(image != nil)
                        {
                            print(image)
                        }

                })
```